# MongoLab not authorized for db.eval

Tags: mongodb, mlab

First I tried db.eval() for my local mogodb server.It is working fine.I used [this example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/)

Then I tried the same thing with MongoLab.But I got this error message.[image]

The error say **not authorized to execute command**.Can you explain why this error message.thanks

Comment: This is really a better question for MongoLab, but since [`db.eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.eval/) requires full admin permissions it seems unlikely that you'd have access to run this command on a non-dedicated server. It's also worth noting that the underlying [`$eval` command](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) is deprecated as at MongoDB 3.0.

Comment: Actually I want to execute a sequence of application-db operations per  one functionality.I think it will makes a huge traffic so needs to encapsulate all the operations into one js function , like Stored Procedures.Is there any other solution for this

Answer (score 1):

Eval is a powerfull, dangerous and deprecated action that mLab don't give.

In a local mongo db you should create a role:

```
use admin
db.createRole(
   {
     role: "dangerEval",
     privileges : [
       { resource: {anyResource: true }, actions : ["anyAction"] },
       // or this for grant anyAction only on a single db:
       { resource: {db: "myDb", collection: "" }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] }
     ],
     roles: []
   }
)
```

Then you can assign this role to a user:

```
db.createUser({
    user: "temporaneyEvalUser",
    pwd: "psw",
    roles: [ { role: "dangerEval", db: "myDb" } ]
});
```

So you have to choose another way to archive your target or change mongo installation.